# Installing printer DeskJet3630 - error : cups missing

Tags: printing, hp, hplip

I have a problem installing printer DeskJet3630 on Ubuntu 20.04.
I have installed hplip version 3.20.3.

When I run `hp-setup` I get error :
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cupsext'

I tried several ways to fix this but without any solution.

Do I have the right hplip version, I wonder ?

Does someone have any clue ?